# Firefox is adding padding to rollover links in wordpress

Tags: php, css, firefox, padding

I've got a rollover menu hard-coded into WordPress (couldn't get IE to recognize the links otherwise). It works fine but there is this mysterious padding on all the links.  I've tried all sorts of stuff - css reset, various positioning settings, adding and removing padding, changing ems to px, removing line height...  Here's the site: http://circore.com/sporttours/

I assume this is the pertinent css, but it could be coming from elsewhere in the style.css file. Any help is appreciated!  thanks

```
#menu-top { 
    background:url(images/menu-top.png);
    height: 115px;  
    width:210px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

#logo {
    display:none;
}

#menu-content { 
    width:210px;
    padding:0px;
    height:238px;

}

#menu-content .img {  
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#menu-bottom { 
    background:url(images/menu-bottom.png) no-repeat;
    height: 302px;
}
```

Comment: There's no padding when I look at it in Firefox (v4 on Mac). Get the Firebug add-in, and you'll be able to see the calculated box model as well as turn individual styles on and off for debugging.

Comment: No padding either on Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Comment: Bizarre - Padding is visible in Firefox 4 (WinXP) but not in Safari, IE, Opera or Chrome.  Nothing jumped out at me using Firebug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix it by changing this:

```
#menu-content .img
{  
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
}
```

to this:

```
#menu-content img
{  
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

- I changed `.img` to just `img`. The difference is important. `.img` is looking for `<img class="img" />` (or *any* element with `class="img"`). You're after finding all `img` elements, so `img` is what you want.
- I can't see the need for `margin: 0; padding: 0` - I assume that was merely part of your attempt to get rid of the extra space.

Comment: Perfect!  thank you SO MUCH!  Think I was just looking at it way too long.

Comment: @thirtydot: is/was this version specific, or am I just blind?

Comment: @Elaine Hey..no fair changing it while I was looking at it.  It's working for me in Firefox now.  Be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen: I'm not sure, but I can tell you that it looked [exactly like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GzRaM.png) for me with Firefox 4.0.1 / Windows 7. It's not such a weird issue though - my Chrome also did the same thing before it was fixed.

Comment: @thirtydot: lol, I saw the same gaps on 3.6.17 XP, but thought these gaps were _by design/intention_. Only checked the padding values of the rollovers with Firebug, which all were 0. Thank you^^